# vifm: show date/time in filelist

Tags: linux, vifm

Is it possible to tell `vifm` to show date and time in the file list, like [here](https://vifm.info/screenshots/reicheltd-light.png)? Currently is showing only file sizes. I want to add date too. I have found the command `set timefmt=%m/%d\ %H:%M` and put it in `~/.vifmrc`, but the date is shown only for the selected file at the bottom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look closer at the screenshot, you'll notice that files are sorted. By default second column is dependent on the sorting and if you sort by modification date, that's what will be in it.  So there was no special setup apart from setting sorting.

If you want to always display modification time before the size, add this to `~/.vifm/vifmrc` (note that it's not`~/.vifmrc` if your post doesn't contain a typo):

```
set viewcolumns=*{name}..,16{mtime},7{}.
```

You might want to check documentation on [`'viewcolumns'`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27viewcolumns%27) option and [column view](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-column-view) to understand the syntax.